# How to customize and add additional features in GeoNode

Tags: python, ubuntu, development, django, geonode

I need some advice on how to start customizing my GeoNode installation. I tried reading up on GeoNode documentations on how to do it but it always boils down to customizing or adding to the Django framework. I am confused on which end should I edit first, should I focus on GeoNode only or should I read up on the Django framework?

Functions I'm trying to add:

- attribute table querying
- multiple feature highlighting
- changing the built in map search function

I am still a bit new to this technology.